# Text to CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv, text, import

I have a little problem about text files transfer to CSV format using PHP. I have a specific format for CSV and I want all of my text to convert to that format. I've written some parts but it didn't work properly. 
Where is my fault?

```
<?php
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option.     Mirum est notare quam littera gothica quam nunc putamus parum claram anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima.";

$charnum="300";
$number=strlen($text);
$repeat=$number/$charnum;
$newtext= str_replace("\n", "", $text);
$newtext = wordwrap($newtext, $charnum, "\n");
$newtext = explode("\n", $newtext);


$keywords = explode("\n", file_get_contents('keywords.txt'));
$title = $keywords[ array_rand($keywords) ];

$cat = explode("\n", file_get_contents('cat.txt'));
$cat = $keywords[ array_rand($keywords) ];

$tag = explode("\n", file_get_contents('tag.txt'));
$tag = $keywords[ array_rand($keywords) ];

$newtext=substr_replace($newtext, '"csv_post_title"/"csv_post_type"/"csv_post_categories"/"csv_post_tags"/"csv_post_post"/"csv_post_date"/"csv_post_excerpt"',0,0);
$newtext=substr_replace($newtext, "\n",121,0);


$newtext=substr_replace($newtext, '"'.$title.'"/""/"'.$cat.'"/"'.$tag.'"/',0,0);

for ( $count=1 ; $count < $repeat ; $count++ ) {
    $file   = "$count.txt";
    file_put_contents($file,$newtext[$count]);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the format supposed to look like? Can you post an example?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes format look like:

`"csv_post_title"/"csv_post_type"/"csv_post_categories"/"csv_post_tags"/"csv_post_post"/"csv_post_date"/"csv_post_excerpt"`

**"recipes"/""/"quick easy dinner recipes"/"foood network"/dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue**